# How to format "Nov 4 2014 12:00:00" into 2014-11-4 12:00:00 in python

Tags: python, datetime

I  have a column value which is actually a string date format "Nov 4 2014 12:00:00" i want to make it a time stamp value  like 2014-11-4 12:00:00. How could i do that i have tried bellow code

```
from datetime import datetime
datetext="Nov 1 2004 12:00:00"
datev= datetime.strptime(datetext,"%YYYY-mm-dd")
print datev
```

and getting this error

```
ValueError: time data 'Nov 1 2004 12:00:00' does not match format '%YYYY-mm-dd'
```

it seems i am missing something here . can anyone guide me

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this should work. `mm` nor `dd` has a percent sign. You are also entirely missing hours minute seconds... There's also no dashes.

Comment: Why not check the table? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Put the correct formatting into strptime to mirror your input:

```
datev = datetime.strptime(datetext,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the formatting directives. ([Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for Python 3.)

---

If you `print` the subsequent `datev` `datetime` object you created, the default `str` formatting of the `datetime` object will be as you requested (2014-11-4 12:00:00). If you want to modify how the printed output looks, use `strftime` as shown in Sardorbek's answer and again, use the formatting directives you desire.

Comment: This parses the date. Doesn't fully answer the question

Comment: @MYGz It was a mistake. Changed to `%H` I see that OP wants to convert "Nov 4 2014 12:00:00" to 2014-11-4 12:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `strptime` wrong https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

After you converted `datetext` to datetime with `strptime` you need to convert it back to string using `strftime` https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime

Using @FeebleOldMan partial answer

```
from datetime import datetime
datetext="Nov 1 2004 12:00:00"
datev = datetime.strptime(datetext,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
new_datetext = datev.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(new_datetext)
```